# Select build info from Jenkins API

Tags: rest, jenkins

Is a way to get info of selected builds with Jenkins2 REST call but without knowledge of job names (i.e. not per job, but from all builds), something like SQL:

```
select number,result from all_builds_in_jenkins;
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You can get everything in a json file, with the following get:

```
http://jenkins.example.com/api/json?tree=jobs[name,builds[number,actions[parameters[name,value]]]]&pretty=true
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "jobs" : [
    {
      "name" : "Job name - Build",
      "builds" : [
        {
          "actions" : [
            {
              "parameters" : [
                {
                  "name" : "GIT_COMMIT_PARAM",
                  "value" : "5447e2f43ea44eb4168d6b32e1a7487a3fdf237f"
                }
              ]
            },
(...)
```

If you need only the list of jobs:

```
http://jenkins.example.com/api/json?tree=jobs[name,color]&pretty=true
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "_class" : "hudson.model.ListView",
  "jobs" : [
    {
      "_class" : "com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder",
      "name" : "DEV"
    },
    {
      "_class" : "com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder",
      "name" : "Libs"
    },
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
      "name" : "Dummy project",
      "color" : "red"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Strange but it selects not all builds. For example it lists me builds 1..36, but I have builds with numbers 200+

Comment: Is it possible to use "depth=N" and to select several builds by its numbers with "xpath=..." ?

Comment: https://.../api/xml?tree=jobs[name,builds[number,result]]&xpath=//*[number=33]  seems to be close to question, but not all builds are selecting. Also I can not understand how to select several builds "(number=N or number=M)" is escaping by Web browser :(

Comment: How do i remove the _class field?